# How to run html code in python with web output using vscode

Tags: python, html, python-webbrowser

I know you guys will remove this question, cause this has been asked, but i can really not understand this question!! Stack overflow has been useless for me due to you guys rejecting my questions even though the answers were hard to understand! Please listen!

The problem:
I have tried to run this code in vscode and was hoping that it would open the web output for the myfile.html:

runner.py

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab('myfile.html')
```

myfile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="inital-scale=1 , width=device-width">
        <title> a file waiting to be opened with python! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1> The top! </h1>
            
            
        </header>
        <main>
            <img src="file.jpg">
            <p> a paragraph</p>
        </main>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and i also have file.jpg in the same folder. But vscode just does nothing ! I have seen on stack overflow and for the other people it has seemed to be working but for me it is not!
Please answer this question, or else i would never use stack overflow again! Also, if there is something wrong with my question or anything else, please tell me and do not close my question!

This was the console output:
cd /Users/aarav/html\ in\ python ; /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/aarav/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.pyt
hon-2023.13.11951037/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 56528 -- /Users/aarav/html\ in\ python/runner.py but it did not open a new tab!

Also PLEASE DO NOT CLOSE THIS QUESTION!!!!

Comment: That code will look for `myfile.html` in the current directory.  Are you sure that is the right place to look?  You can show the current directory with this code `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`webbrowser.open_new_tab` requires a URL, not a file path.**

To specify local files in a URL use the `file://absolute/path/to/file/` scheme:

```
import webbrowser
import os

webbrowser.open_new_tab(f"file://{os.path.abspath('myfile.html')}")
```

This code uses the `os` module to get the absolute path of the file, and then convert it to a URL. You could use a server to serve the file and then use the servers url.

Comment: thank you for not deleting this! Yes i got this answer somewhere else but thank you!